# Met-on une majuscule aux exonymes péjoratifs ?

Tags: majuscules, insultes, gentilés

*En préambule, je précise qu’en plus des règles de SE, je ne souhaite pas faire de provocation, ni de conflit haineux malsaint. Néanmoins la question typographique se pose vraiment.*

J’entends par « exonyme pejoratif » un nom injurieux qu’utilise une population donné pour désigner une autre. Je préfère éviter, pour les raisons sus-citées, d’en donner des exemples ici.

En fait, je me posais la question car si ces noms sont assimilables à des gentilés, et que les gentilés prennent une majuscule, alors à priori ils en prennent aussi.
Je me posais la question car je devais faire verbatim d’une altercation, et au moment où j’ai du écrire l’exonyme injurieux, j’ai hésité à appuyer sur la touche de basculement de casse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si le mot désigne les habitants d'un lieu précis, on peut très bien utiliser une majuscule comme pour les autres gentilés mais rien n'interdit non plus de considérer qu'il s'agit d'un adjectif avec ellipse du nom auquel il s'applique et de laisser le mot en minuscules.

Voici par exemple un texte où *boches* (Allemands) est en minuscules (ellipse de *soldats* ou *fantassins*) mais *macaronis* (Italiens) a une majuscule.

> Hier dans les tranchées des fantassins on entendait les **b**oches chanter en français dans leurs boyaux :
>     *Ah! Qu'ils sont bons quand ils sont cuits
>
>                    Les **M**acaronis…*
> C'était, ma parole, pour nous narguer à propos des Italiens qui mettent tant de temps à se décider.
>
> Guillaume Appolinaire, *Tendre comme le souvenir*, 1915